# Rerun failed SoapUI tests in testsuite teardown script

Tags: groovy, soapui, teardown

I would like to rerun tests that have failed in a testsuite run. What script would I use in the teardown script of the testsuite that would rerun any failures?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the SoapUI website: http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#8-2-logging-the-result-messages-of-all-teststeps-in-all-failing-testcases should not be too difficult to use `testCase.run()` instead of the `log.info()`.